# OpenNi: set Player node for OpenFileRecording

Tags: c++, kinect, openni

I searched on web for this problem but I didn't find a solution.

I'm starting to use samples of OpenNI to develop my application. I have not  much experience with C++: I am a beginner.

I'm using SimpleSkeleton sample of OpenNI 1.5.4 which returns head position. I need it but using an ONI file which I got recording using NiViewer, and not the stream data from kinect.

Searching on web I found:

```
xn::Context context;
xn::Player player; 
nRetVal = context.Init();   
nRetVal=context.OpenFileRecording("Myfile.oni",player);
if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)
{
    printf("Can't open recording file: %s\n",xnGetStatusString(nRetVal));
    return 1;
}
```

My code enter the `if` loop, print 'Can't open my file.oni ...' and doesn't continue running.
I think the problem is to set player object. How can I do? Or what have I to do?

Without the lines:

```
nRetVal=context.OpenFileRecording("Myfile.oni",player);
if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)
{
    printf("Can't open recording file: %s\n",xnGetStatusString(nRetVal));
    return 1;
}
```

it runs correctly but use data stream from kinect and not from file.

Comment: So the question is: How to stream from a file instead of directly from the Kinect or did i miss something?
Second, are you sure file exists and are in the path of the program?

Comment: For the first: I want head position from file recorded and not using kinect. I would plug-off it during execution. For the second: I put the complete address, i.e: "D:\...\...\Myfile.oni"

Comment: I also put the file in the same folder but I got the same problem

Comment: None one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Even if it seems like it's not, this is a path issue.
I had a similar problem, you're either passing it to OpenNI in a way it does no like, or the path is not valid.

How are you retrieving the path? Trying using boost to get the current-directory and then appending the .oni file name to that string